# C++ : Why my string is not getting printed?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to convert time from 12 hour format to 24 hour format. It is a hackerrank question which I am trying to solve. Here is my code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string timeConversion(string s) {
    string r;
    int hh,mm,ss;
    hh = (s[0]-'0')*10+(s[1]-'0');
    mm = (s[3]-'0')*10+(s[4]-'0');
    ss = (s[6]-'0')*10+(s[7]-'0');

    if(hh<12 && s[8] == 'P') hh +=12;
    if(hh == 12 && s[8]=='A') hh = 0;
    r[0]=hh/10+'0';
    r[1]=hh%10+'0';
    r[2]=':';
    r[3]=mm/10+'0';
    r[4]=mm%10+'0';
    r[5]=':';
    r[6]=ss/10+'0';
    r[7]=ss%10+'0';
    r[8]='\0';

    return r;
}

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    string result = timeConversion(s);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is giving blank output. Though when I cout result[0] then this gives me proper result.

Comment: `r` has size `0`.

Comment: You never add any characters to `r`.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` is a risky combination. The first includes pretty much the entire standard library. She second places the tens of thousands of identifiers that were just included into the global namespace where they will compete with any identifiers you declare. This can result in extremely arcane error messages and utterly bizarre runtime behaviour as stuff you didn't even knew existed gets used instead of what you had intended. Use with extreme caution and prefer not to do it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

> ### operator []
>
> No bounds checking is performed. If `pos > size()`, the behavior is undefined.

When you define `string r`, its `size()` is zero, so all your character assignments are undefined behaviors. You may want to [resize it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) first:

```
r.resize(9);
```

Or alternatively, [append the characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) one-by-one:

```
r = "";
r.push_back(hh/10+'0');
r.push_back(hh%10+'0');
r.push_back(':');
r.push_back(mm/10+'0');
r.push_back(mm%10+'0');
r.push_back(':');
r.push_back(ss/10+'0');
r.push_back(ss%10+'0');
// This isn't necessary
// r.push_back('\0');
```

Using `operator+=` makes your code look more natural:

```
r = "";
r += hh/10+'0';
r += hh%10+'0';
r += ':';
r += mm/10+'0';
r += mm%10+'0';
r += ':';
r += ss/10+'0';
r += ss%10+'0';
// This isn't necessary
// r += '\0';
```

Note you don't need the terminating zero because `std::basic_string` isn't null-terminated (it's not C-style string).

Comment: Or use `+=` to make it more natural.

Comment: Also, you don't need this: `r = "";`. The string is empty by default. And, you also don't need this: `r += '\0';`. An `std::string` does not need to be NULL-terminated.

Comment: @NikosC. It's OP's code that adds a terminating zero.

Comment: Yes, but it's a good idea to point out mistakes and/or false assumptions in answers.

Comment: @NikosC. Got you. Added it